# Getting error Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String

Tags: java

I have encountered this error "Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String". I see that this is a fairly common question amongst Java newbies, and while I've attempted to apply the advice to my code, but I haven't had any success. I am hoping to get some feedback and suggestions on how to hopefully get this running properly. I am able to get it functioning properly using println, but having the output formatted is required for an assignment. Any advice would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

```
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 public class UserIO {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    // initialize coefficients.
            double a;
            double b;
            double c;
            // int counter = 0;

            String userInput; // take a String for input.

            // display message. returns null.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Welcome. Input positive a real number for a, b, and c. Numbers must range between 1.0 -10.0");
            userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a real number for a.");
            a = Double.parseDouble(userInput);// convert String userInput to real
                                                // numbers.
            System.out.println("Number for a = " + userInput); // print a

            userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a real number for b. ");
            b = Double.parseDouble(userInput);
            System.out.println("Number for b = " + b); // print b

            userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a real number for c.");
            c = Double.parseDouble(userInput);
            System.out.println("Number for c = " + c); // print c

            // calculate quadratic equation 5 times, store in xValues then, print to
            // screen.

            double product;
            double[] xValues = new double[5]; // array index of 5.

            for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {

                xValues[i] = i + 1; // fills array with numbers 1-5.
                // raise x to the i'th degree.
                product = a * Math.pow(xValues[i], 2) + b * xValues[i] + c;

                // System.out.println("[" + i + "]"+ " " + xValues[i] + " " +// product);
                System.out.printf("%d , i  " + "%1.2f ", xValues[i] + " " + "%1.3f ", product);

            } // end loop

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I guess this line causes theproblem:

```
System.out.printf("%d , i  " + "%1.2f ", xValues[i] + " " + "%1.3f ", product);
```

which can be simplified to:

```
System.out.printf("%d , i  %1.2f ", xValues[i] + " %1.3f ", product);
```

Here you can clearly see that you try to replace `%d` with the string `xValues[i] + " %1.3f "`.

I thinky you intended somethig different.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the API, it should be like shown below.

```
System.out.printf("%d , %1.2f , %1.3f ", i, xValues[i], product);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I I have the error "Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '1' ".

Comment: @Raven you are doing mistake with formatting syntex 
 please look at this post and let us know in case if have any issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442728/java-unknownformatconversionexception